# How to parse たすけにいって

Tags: grammar

How to parse たすけにいって in 子猫をたすけにいって 子猫にかまれたらしい

I think I understand the overall meaning, "It seems that he went to save the kitten and got bitten" but i want to understand more about the に いって.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12628/7810

Answer (score 6):

Adding particle に to the i-form (also called stem, masu-form, etc.) indicates a **purpose** for going somewhere.

In your case, the purpose for going is to *save the cat*. So, as you guessed, "He went to save the kitten" is a good translation.

Other simple examples of this grammar construct:

> 映画を見に行った
>   I went to see a movie
>
> ゲームを買いに行く
>   I'm going to buy a game
>
> 友達に会いに行った
>   I went to see my friends

Comment: Tangential, but I find it helpful to consider this type of usage of the masu-stem as a "limited-noun-like" usage, since it takes a particle and "feels nouny".   A lot of the older verbs' masu-stems are actually "living, breathing" nouns in their own right, up to and including ditching the おくりがな (eg 話｛はなし｝).

Answer (score 2):

しに行く means "go to do" and this て means "and then".

行っ is a euphonic change of 行き which is masu-form of 行く. I think your translation is good.

Comment: `助けに行っ is a euphonic change of 助けに行く` -> 促音化して「行っ」になったのは、(「行く」ではなく) 連用形の「行き」、と言った方がよいかもしれませんね。（行きて -> 行って）

Comment: Yes, it is rightness.