# Why is kiru represented as kiri in おじいさん が 山 へ 木 を きり に いけば

Tags: renyōkei, verbs-of-motion

I can't fathom why the verb kiru is in the masu form without the masu attached in this sentence:

> おじいさん が 山{やま} へ 木{き} を きり に いけば

What is the purpose?

Comment: Closely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56428/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54211/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12628/7810

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of に after verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54211/usage-of-%e3%81%ab-after-verbs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may make sense of this grammar pattern if you know [the masu-stem of a verb can act as a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010). As you probably know, に is a particle that usually takes a **noun** representing a destination, a goal, a resulting status, etc. It roughly corresponds to the English prepositions *to*, *for* or *into*.

So you can use ～に行く with simple nouns and suru-verbs:

- 買い物に行く to go for shopping
- 面接に来る to come to take a job interview

Likewise, when you use ～に行く with a verb representing a purpose, a form that has a noun-like quality is expected, and this is where the masu-stem comes into play:

- 映画を見に行く
- 遊びに出かける

That being said, I think this `masu-stem + motion verb` construction should be learned by rote. So-called "masu-stem" has various usages, and it may not be always possible to explain it logically. After all, "masu-stem" (or 連用形) was named after its most important function, but its usage is not limited to what the name suggests. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65953/5010) for details.